# Having trouble finding my iOS device ID and connecting to APNS server for Push Notifications in PHP

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have tried for days to retrieve my device token as well as use the following PHP script to send a simple Push Notification to all users of my app who have allowed notifications yet I have had no success. I am confused on how to even get my device token and the script will not connect to APNS servers.

```
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsCert = 'pushcert.pem';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsPass = '<MYPASS>';
$token = '<MYDEVICETOKEN>';

$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'You have new comments!', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
$output = json_encode($payload);
$token = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token));
$apnsMessage = chr(0).chr(0).chr(32).$token.chr(0).chr(strlen($output)).$output;

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $apnsPass);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://'.$apnsHost.':'.$apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
fclose($apns);
```

Comment: The device token is provided to the app delegate method `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications` - you need code in that method to store the token in a database that your server can access when it wants to send a push

Comment: So I should run that in XCode? This is a Cordova made app.

Comment: I don't know anything about Cordova development, but a quick google seems to indicate that you have an AppDelegate.m file that implements the app delegate in Objective C, so yes, that code would need to go there.